# Need to measure high resistance values

Tags: resistance

I'm needing to measure the coil resistance in several potential relays used in HVAC/R applications, and my current HVAC Fluke meter #902 is only able to read the resistance values in a few of them, I suspect because the resistance is too high for the meter to measure. Presently, I have readings that range from 2245 through 9945, but need to read quite a bit much higher, likely up to around 15K ohms. My question is, are that any other quality multi-meters available that will measure this level of resistance? Thank you, Gary

Comment: Most general-purpose DVMs should measure resistance into the Megohm range.

Answer (score 2):

15kOhm is well within the range of common multimeters. I did look up your particular model and noticed that there is no spec given for >10kOhm, so you may be correct that your meter is not designed to measure these impedances.  See page 23 [here](http://www.testequipmentdepot.com/fluke/pdf/902_manu.pdf).

[Here](http://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/3320multimeter.php) is an example of a low cost multimeter that could fit your needs. If you are interested in another Fluke, the 115 looks like a reasonable option.

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance. Much appreciated and glad to know.